# Creating a new file inside a path in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, writefile

I have a path in the file system, say

```
/home/user/lannister/wines/red/knowthings
```

Inside `lannister` folder, my nodejs code resides. What the code is supposed to do, is, to create a blank file called `debtslist.txt` which should be located inside `knowthings` folder, so that the file path becomes

```
/home/user/lannister/wines/red/knowthings/debtslist.txt
```

I tired several ways of doing it, that include:

```
const filePath = 'wines/red/knowthings/debtslist.txt';
fs.openSync(filePath, 'w');
```

and

```
const filePath = 'wines/red/knowthings/debtslist.txt';
fs.writeFile(filePath, '', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});
```

But every time I am getting this error:

```
Error
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'wines/red/knowthings/debtslist.txt'
```

Am I specifying the path in `const filePath` in a wrong way?

Comment: `'wines/red/knowthings/debtslist.txt'` is a relative path, what is it relative TO? (Log `process.cwd())`).

Comment: The code runs without error when I test it. The path must just be relative to the wrong place.

Comment: You need to run the script relative to `/home/user/lannister/` folder. Or use absolute path `const homedir = require('os').homedir(); const filePath = homedir + '/lannister/wines/red/knowthings/debtslist.txt'`

Comment: @Quentin I just tried building the filePath as `const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "wines", "red", "knowsthings", debtslist.txt")` and ran the code. The error still shows up as `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/lannister/wines/red/knowthings/debtslist.txt'`

Comment: You made a typo. Missing `"` and missing `s` (between `know` and `things`).

Comment: @Quentin ok so that was definitely a fabricated path which was typed with mistake in last comment :D and let me re-declare the path as `const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "wines", "red", "knowthings", "debtslist.txt")`. Now this produces the error `Error:  ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/lannister/wines/red/knowthings/debtslist.txt'`

Comment: @harshvardhan — Runs without errors when I test it.

Comment: @Quentin hey I solved it. Though it did not need me to finally set the full path and I got to work it with relative path, the file was actually not getting created because of async. It happened that I was creating the folder `knowthings` first and then write a file inside that. Because of async, node many times was trying to create file before creating the folder. So I placed the operation to create file inside callback of the operation to create folder. Now it works perfectly.